# Problem with mapping and managing entity, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities: Dish and Ingredient. I would like to add ingredients to dishes.
When I was doing it with `@ManyToMany` relationship it works (I added, deleted, get all Dishes with table of ingredients - my endpoints works), but now I want to add extra column in cross-table `DishIngredient`.

So what I did was:

- remove `@ManyToMany`, added `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToOne`
- added cross-table as entity (java class) and added extra field (as my extra column in db)

Now, when I want for example GET all dishes or single dish by id I get error:

```
2020-06-25 17:01:25.995 ERROR 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : BŁĄD: column ingredient1_.id does not exist
  Pozycja: 406
2020-06-25 17:01:26.000  WARN 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->.springbootdemo.dish.domain.Dish["dishIngredient"])]
```

My code is here, on branch: https://github.com/rhquee/MealsOrganizerApp/tree/mapping_many_to_many_extra_column

My DB is:

[image]

How can I manage this cross-table (cross-class)?

Comment: DishIngredient.java -> Remove `@Id` from Dish & Ingredient instance variables. Add a new variable `@Id private Integer id;` Otherwise you have to go with `@EmbeddedId`, @johnmule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is create db schema by Hibernate. Firstly change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` or `create-drop`. Then remove `@id` annotiation in model `DishIngredient` on `dish` and `ingredient` column and add `ReferencedColumn` to `@JoinColumn`. Also you need add all essential methods in repo and service to model `DishIngredient`.

Answer (score 0):

Change hibernate configuration

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

by

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

It creates the schema and destroying previous data each time you build app.
It's quite good option for initial project building.